# How to get cv2 Mat from C++ vector?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, vector

I'm trying to get a sequence of image from float vector (N, H, W, C), where each channel have `float` values in the range 0..1.

What I'm trying to do for each image is:

1. Convert float vector (HWC) to cv2 `Mat` type.
2. Change RGB to BGR, and multiply 255 (to make values 0~255)
3. Convert to uint8 type `Mat`.
4. Get image. (`imwrite`)

So I tried this in this way below.
This code doesn't make error. but isn't working.
Please let me know how to do this!

```
vector<float> output(batch_size * orig_height * orig_width*3); //N H W C

for(int bat=0; bat < batch_size; bat++){
    Mat result(width, height, CV_32F, (void*)(output.data()+ bat*height*width*3));
    cv::cvtColor(result, result, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);
    result = result * 255.0;
    result.convertTo(result, CV_8U);
    
    cv::imwrite(file_name, result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are several issues in your code:**

1. When you create `cv::Mat`s, the element data type also includes the number of channels.
   This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#af2d2652e552d7de635988f18a84b53e5).
   Since you have 3 channel images, you need to change `CV_32F` to `CV_32FC3` and `CV_8U` to `CV_8UC3`.
2. The `cv::Mat` [constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a) that you use expects to get the dimensions as `int rows, int cols` (in that order). Therefore you need to swap the width and height you pass to the ctor.
3. Color conversion RGB->BGR should be done after converting to a uint8 image.

**Fixed version:**

```
std::vector<float> output(batch_size * orig_height * orig_width * 3, 0.5); //N H W C

for (int bat = 0; bat < batch_size; bat++) {
    cv::Mat result(orig_height, orig_width, CV_32FC3, (void*)(output.data() + bat * orig_height * orig_width * 3));
    result = result * 255.0;
    result.convertTo(result, CV_8UC3);
    cv::cvtColor(result, result, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);
    cv::imwrite(file_name, result);
}
```

**A side note:** better to avoid `using namespace std;` - see here: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).